# Behat test fails, unable to find Username field using @javascript

Tags: 8, testing

My Behat test fails as soon as I add `@javascript`

Error:

> ```
> Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "Username" not found.
> ```

When I remove `@javascript`, test is passed without any error.

```
Given I am logged in as a user with the Administrator role
```

To test the Drupal 8 `image_field` I need `@javascript`

Behat.yml:

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': '%paths.base%/tests/behat/bootstrap'
  suites:
    default:
      paths:
        - '%paths.base%/tests/behat/default'
      contexts:
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - MyServices\EntityContext
        - FailureContext
        - MyServices\LinkContext
        - My\MenuContext
  extensions:
    Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
      image_drivers:
        local:
          screenshot_directory: /[SHARED_FOLDER]/screenshots
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      base_url: "http://dev.mysite.com"
      files_path: '%paths.base%/tests/behat/files/'
      javascript_session: selenium2
      browser_name: chrome
      selenium2:
        wd_host: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
        capabilities:
          # required by mink-extension 2.3
          marionette: null
          browserName: chrome
          browser: chrome
          version: 63
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      api_driver: 'drupal'
      drupal:
        drupal_root: '%paths.base%/public'
      text:
        username_field: "Username"
        password_field: "Password"
        log_in: "Log in"
        log_out: "Log out"
      selectors:
        message_selector: '.messages'
        error_message_selector: '.messages--error'
        success_message_selector: '.messages--status'
        warning_message_selector: '.messages--warning'
        logged_in_selector: '.user-logged-in'
        login_form_selector: '#user-login-form'
      region_map:
        comments: '.comments'
        "main navigation": '#block-my-theme-main-navigation'
        "local tasks": '.block--local-tasks-block'
        "main content": '.block--system-main-block'
        "highlights": '.c-highlights__list'

ci:
  extensions:
    Bex\Behat\ScreenshotExtension:
      image_drivers:
        local:
          screenshot_directory: /tmp/artifacts/screenshots
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://localhost
```

Comment: Does that form field exist and is “Username” the literal value in one of those attributes?

Comment: We'd need to see your `behat.yml` and your complete scenario to narrow things down. Could you update your question to add these?

Comment: @Kevin yes it exist and also the Username and Password fields from Drupal core.

Comment: You should give [`bex/behat-screenshot`](https://github.com/elvetemedve/behat-screenshot) a try to let it make screenshots of failed steps. Do you use Selenium?

Comment: But are you checking for the "title" as in what you see? Isn't @javascript locating it in the DOM?

Comment: You could either add the requested info to your question or let us go on guessing which then makes this question too broad. When you have Selenium and chromedriver it should actually open a Chromium to let you see what you get. Is "Username" there then?

Answer (score 4):

I bet you are either one:

1. Testing against a non-English site.
2. Having BigPipe enabled.
3. Missed to tag that scenario with `@api`.
4. Misconfigured Selenium.

---

To solve 1. you need to put the non-English strings into your `behat.yml` like so:

```
Drupal\DrupalExtension:
  text:
    log_out: "Sign out"
    log_in: "Sign in"
    password_field: "Enter your password"
    username_field: "Username"
```

@see docs [Override text strings](https://behat-drupal-extension.readthedocs.io/en/master/blackbox.html#override-text-strings).

---

To solve 2. which can occur when BigPipe somehow changes the markup in an undesired way, you can try out the patch at https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/pull/325.patch.

@see pull request [Big pipe compatibility follow-up](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension/pull/325)

---

To solve 3. simply add an `@api` tag to your scenario.

---

To solve 4. you must point `wd_host` to `http://dev.mysite.com:4444/wd/hub`, since your `base_url` is `http://dev.mysite.com`.

```
wd_host: "http://dev.mysite.com:4444/wd/hub"
```

Comment: **1)** The site is one language Dutch. But it's not translated yet. **2)** BigPipe isn't enabled. **3)** I have this already in my behat.yml `text:
        username_field: "Username"
        password_field: "Password"
        log_in: "Log in"
        log_out: "Log out"`

Comment: and I have already `@api` tag.

Comment: I added my behat.yml.

Comment: @meez – Chromium never displayed you the site, right? That's also why the screenshots are empty. As it must be configured like that: `wd_host: "http://dev.mysite.com:4444/wd/hub"`.

Comment: sorry to be sure. What is Chromium exactly? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @meez – chromedriver, you must have chromedriver installed to let Selenium launch a browser, a Chromium browser. It will open up, you can look at it, you'll see what's going on during your tests.

Comment: I tried your code but no screenshots are taken? Do you have a clue?

Comment: @meez – Yes. The session probably never started. See https://github.com/elvetemedve/behat-screenshot/pull/49