# How to execute login feature on Chrome browser

Tags: 8, testing

Just using Behat with drupal 8 and facing problem with login behat script to run. Below are the my code :

behat.yml

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte: ~
      base_url: http://localhost:8080/drupal-dev/web
      javascript_session: selenium2
      browser_name: 'chrome'
      selenium2: ~
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      api_driver: drupal
      drupal:
        drupal_root: web/
      region_map:
        navigation: ".navbar-header"
        navigation_collapsible: "#navbar-collapse"
        header: ".region-header"
        highlighted: ".highlighted"
        help: ".region-help"
        content: ".region-content"
        sidebar_first: ".region-sidebar-first"
        sidebar_second: ".region-sidebar-second"
        footer: ".footer"
```

login.feature

```
@javascript
Feature: login check

Scenario: user login is working
  Given I am on "/user"
  When I fill in "john" for "edit-name"
  And I fill in "john for "edit-pass"
  And I press "Log in"
  Then I should see "Add content"
```

While i execute the vendor\bin\behat then it will open the chrome browser and redirect to user login page but failed from second step. See below error message :

```
@javascript
Feature: login check

  Scenario: user login is working             # features\bootstrap\login.feature:4
    Given I am on "/user"                     # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::visit()
    When I fill in "john" for "edit-name"   # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::fillField()
      Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "edit-name" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
    And I fill in "john" for "edit-pass" # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::fillField()
    And I press "Log in"                      # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::pressButton()
    Then I should see "Add content"           # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::assertPageContainsText()

--- Failed scenarios:

    features\bootstrap\login.feature:4

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 passed, 1 failed, 3 skipped)
0m15.30s (17.82Mb)
```

And same feature file working fine and all steps passed if i replaced from @javasript to @api.

Comment: Have you already tried putting both? `@api @javascript`?

Comment: Do you maybe have BigPipe enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved the issue via changing selenium server version from 3.1 to 2.53

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `@javascript` tagged scenario that's working for me.

```
Feature: Login testing.

  @javascript
  Scenario: Testing the user cant login with bas credentials.
    Given I visit "user/login"
    And I fill in "name" with "foo"
    And I fill in "pass" with "bar"
    When I press "op"
    Then I should see an ".error" element
```

Comment: Big pipe module is enabled and see below error when try to execute your scenario :

1 scenario (1 undefined)
6 steps (1 passed, 1 undefined, 4 skipped)
0m18.60s (17.85Mb)

 >> default suite has undefined steps. Please choose the context to generate snippets:

  [0] None
  [1] FeatureContext
  [2] Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
  [3] Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
  [4] Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MessageContext
  [5] Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrushContext

Comment: Remove the unrelated steps. And see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/275652/15055

Comment: Which one is unrelated steps.  Please suggest if i was doing something wrong.

Comment: @VernitGupta – See my updated answer. You can also simply find it out yourself by removing steps one by one until you got it and then add all others back. Please try to solve this systematically yourself.

Comment: Updated answer and feature in my question are same. Same error received "Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "name" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)"